# Gradle - Executor singleton not started

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

When doing `./gradlew assembleDebug` gradle gives me this error :

> Build exception
>   Executor singleton not started

This was working fine with a project I cloned from github, until I deleted it and **cloned a new one.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was using `Gradle Daemon` to speed up the builds, I suspected the exception had something to do with the Daemon so I restarted it and now it's working fine. Here's the command to stop the daemon :

```
./gradlew --stop
```

The next time you do a build it starts automatically.

Comment: I encounter this frequently when switching Git branches on an Android project in IntelliJ/Android Studio. This fixed for me as well.